# JAVA Convert 2d array of strings to 2d array of Number type

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, types, numbers

i have got little problem. I scanned numbers from .csv file into 2d array of strings. Now i need to parse it into 2d array of Number type. Not int or double. 
The error says:

Required type:
com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.Number
Provided:
java.lang.Number

Can you please take a look ?

```
 for (int a = 0; a < rows; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < cols; b++) {
            parsedContent[a][b] = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(arrayOfStrings[a][b]);   
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a small sample programm for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        int rows = 2;
        int cols = 3;

        String[][] arrayOfStrings = {{"1.1","2.222222222","3.333"},{"4.44","5555","666"}};

        Number[][] parsedContent = new Number[rows][cols];

        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);

        for (int a = 0; a < rows; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < cols; b++) {
                parsedContent[a][b] = numberFormat.parse(arrayOfStrings[a][b]);
                System.out.println(parsedContent[a][b]);
            }
        }
}
```

Outout:

```
1.1
2.222222222
3.333
4.44
5555
666
```

Is that what you mean? Otherwise I need more code details and some sample Strings.